# how to browse a webpage(Page by Page) using webcontrol in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Through Windows app i want to  login into website using webcontrol automatically and i need  to search and browse the web pages .. here is my eg:

In load event

```
       Dim webAddress As String = "http:XXXXXXXx"
            '  WebControl2.WebView.Url = webAddress
            WebControl2.WebView.LoadUrlAndWait(webAddress)
            WebControl2.WebView.EvalScript("document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value = 'xxxxxx';")
            WebControl2.WebView.EvalScript("document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value = 'yyyyy';")
            WebControl2.WebView.EvalScript("document.getElementsByName('username')[0].focus();")
            WebControl2.WebView.EvalScript("document.getElementsByName('password')[0].focus();")
            WebControl2.WebView.SetFocus()
            WebControl2.WebView.EvalScript("document.getElementByInputType('submit')[0].click();") 
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")  
SendKeys.Send(ControlChars.Cr)
```

it works fine but i could't access the page which i have loged in

Comment: `WebControl` is not a standard .NET control.  What is it?

Comment: EO.Web Controls is a third party dll refrence for chrome engine